# PUT и DELETE запросы django

Tags: python, django

Пытаюсь уже несколько дней разобраться, как отправлять запросы put и delete через django, пока найти ответ не удалось.

Вот, что есть сейчас:

views.py

```
class AllRoutes(View):

model = Schedule
template_name = 'trains_schedule/all_routes.html'

def get(self,request,train_id=None):
    if train_id:
        train = Schedule.objects.get(pk=int(train_id))
        context = {'train':train}
    else:
        context = {'schedule_list':Schedule.objects.all()}
    return render(request,'trains_schedule/all_routes.html',context)

def delete(self,request,train_id=None):
    route = get_object_or_404(Schedule, pk=train_id)
    response = u'Successful delete route {}'.format(route.display_name())
    route.delete()
    return HttpResponse(response)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^trains/(?P<train_id>[0-9]+)?$', views.AllRoutes.as_view(), name='trains')]
```

all_routes.html

```
{% if schedule_list %}
<h3>{{ "List of all train routes" }}</h3>
<ul>
{% for train_route in schedule_list %}
    <li><a href="{% url 'trains' train_route.id %}">{{ train_route.display_name }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
{% else %}
<p></p>
{% endif %}

{% if train %}
<h1>{{ train.train }}</h1>

<h3>{{ "Route info" }}</h3>
{{ train.display_train }}

<h3>{{ "Train info" }}</h3>
{{train.display_train_info}}

<form  method="delete">
{% csrf_token %}
<input type="submit" value="Delete" />
</form>
{% else %}
<p></p>
{% endif %}
```

Как функционирует сейчас:

- переход по /trains/ показывает список всех маршрутов в виде ссылок на страницу каждого отдельного маршрута
- переход по /trains/12 - get() в views.py получает id поезда и выводит по нему информацию, так же отображает кнопку delete

И вот нужно, чтобы по нажатию на delete формировался DELETE запрос, как сделать, чтобы так было я не понимаю.

Как вариант сделал вот так:

```
<form  method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
<input id="action_id" type="hidden" name="action" value="Delete">
<input type="submit" value="Delete" />
</form>
```

и во views.py добавил соответствующую обработку post запроса с action_id =="Delete"

Однако, хотелось бы именно DELETE и PUT запросы делать, а не парсить, данные полученные из POST запроса, и на их основе менять или удалять маршруты.

Понимаю, что нужно модифицировать вот этот кусок:

```
<form  method="delete">
{% csrf_token %}
<input type="submit" value="Delete" />
</form>
```

Но, что именно нужно сделать разобраться не удалось.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML формы в большинстве браузеров пока не умеют ничего кроме POST и GET. Если хотите использовать DELETE - делайте ajax запрос с соответствующим методом. Например с помощью jquery:

```
<input type="submit" value="Delete" class="delete_item" data-id="666" />

<script>
    $(function() {
        $('.delete_item').on('click', function() {
            var $btn = $(this);
            var id = $btn.data('id');
            $.ajax({
                url: '/trains/' + id + '/',
                type: 'DELETE',
                success: function(response) {
                    // Какое либо действие после удаления, например переход на другую страницу или ее обновление
                    location.reload();
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```